# Which proxy can bypass corporate proxy warning pages?

Tags: proxy

The company I work for has some paranoid security policies, some sites are blacklisted, some are whitelisted and that is ok. The problem is that 99.99% sites I visit are neither blacklisted, nor blacklisted. And when I enter such site (e.g. superuser.com or stackoverflow.com) first thing I see is a warning page, that says that this is a not white-list site, and I could proceed, but all my actions would be logged and violations prosecuted. And this page contains a "Continue" button that submits a confirmation to a corporate proxy and redirects you to the page you wanted.

This is too annoying, and I wrote a Greasemonkey script for clicking that button automatically. That solves the problem in my browser, but this is not enough.

Lots of software I use daily (as Java programmer) uses http-based services. E.g. IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse download plugins using plain http. But the first thing they see when trying to download a plugin list is a corporate proxy warning, and of course this breaks the plugin repository interaction.

I have an idea to put some smart proxy between my software and corporate proxy, so that it would "click" the "Continue" button in background and pretend that this warning page did not appear. I.e. create a chain like (software) -> (smart proxy) -> (corporate proxy). But don't know any "smart proxy" software that can handle the problem.

EDIT: My workstation is Windows 7 machine with local admin rights.

Comment: You're a Java programmer, code one yourself. I don't think there is one!

Comment: Quit your job!, a bit sarcastic I know.

Comment: Easy for non java programmers to make comments like the above.. But i'm not sure that java is really meant for that kind of thing.. since it's not designed really to interact with the machine directly. the program perhaps isn't even meant to exist outside of the JVM..   Also socket programming is quite advanced. Perhaps it can be done..But it's not easy or obvious.. it's easier said than done, and particularly easy for people to suggest that it's trivial when they  don't know how to do it themselves.

Comment: Ok, advice to write one is trivial. I can do that and have had some experience writing smart proxies before. But really smart choice would be to get a ready-to-go and customizable solution instead of ad-hoc one.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Take the matter up with the IT department. If they are paranoid security wise, I wouldn't expect them to react well if they discover you've taken steps to avoid or nullify their warnings. They may just be able to put an exception in for your workstation.

When all is said and done these are company policies, and its the only sensible option.

Comment: This is a huge bank, and no exceptions are made for IT department, leaving alone single workstations. Even dl.sourceforge.net and mirrors are banned, can you imagine that?

Comment: for workstations in a bank, yes. For the IT department, not so much.